# Android: DatabaseObjectNotClosedException in OnUpgarde although its closed

Tags: android, database, exception

edit: 
My Database has 2 Tables. One Table is user data which needs to be saved and restored after a update. The other table is constant data which is loaded from the assets folder on every update.

So when I upgrade the database I first save table one to an external db. Then I overwrite the database by `copyDataBase();` with has the 'constant' table and then copy the saved table back.

Before I copy the db I need to close it otherwise the data is weird. I always get an

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.myproject/databases/mdb.sqlite'
```

where openOrCreateDatabase is called.
That is strange because i called close before. What can I do?

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,
        int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

//save db tables to other db ...

db.close(); 
copyDataBase();
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, null);

//... save back to db
}
```

thanks
Euribor

Comment: You **DON'T** show **WHERE** the error is occurring. In `copyDataBase();` or in `db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, null);`? You don't show any code in these methods either. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: my copyDataBase() from here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/. anyway, it doesnt do anything related to the error message, its just a hint to get the feeling what my function does. and the crash is happening in openOrCreateDatabase as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to *not* close the database that is open while the `onUpgrade` will be performed. You are interfering a sensible action that will cause a lot of trouble!

You should consider other mechanism to find out if a database was upgraded and do your backup/copy.

*edit*

If you just want to replace one table from the assets folder, why don't you just copy the database on the sdcard, open a connection and replace the table content from the internal with the one from the assets database? This can be done in the onUpgrade without closing the internal database.

You shouldn't copy database files around just to replace/update a single table.

Comment: what sensible action do you think of? All it does is a simple
if (version != DATABASE_VERSION) {
             try {
                 if (version == 0) {
                  onCreate(myDataBase);
                 } else {
                     onUpgrade(myDataBase, version, DATABASE_VERSION);
                 }
within a transaction

Comment: you are calling that inside your onUpgrade? It seems pretty confusing what you are doing... from what I read, I would say what ever you do or try to do: you do it the wrong way. Could you explain in your question what you actually try to achieve?

Comment: your proposal to copy the table is a bit better than copying the whole database. But I still see problems with onUpgrade. To copy the tables needs to attach the sd card database. This is not possible within a transaction which the calling function of OnUpgrade starts. I can end the transaction, but thats not what is intended.